# Exporting Selected Feature to New Shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, export, select

I currently have a search cursor iterating through a shapefile in ArcGIS 10.1 that selects a feature and runs a viewshed analysis on that feature (and only that feature). 
What's the easiest way to also export that same feature to a shapefile with the same name in Python?

```
fieldFID = 'FID'
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (inPoints, "pts")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('pts',[fieldFID]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        fid = str(row[0])
        print fid
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("pts", "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = {}'.format(fid))
        outViewshed = Viewshed(inDEM,"pts",1,"CURVED_EARTH",0.15)
        outViewshed.save("C:/temp/output/viewsheds/"+fid)
```

Comment: Generally speaking, all ArcGIS GP operations behave on 1) the selected features , and 2) the whole data set if none is selected.  Therefore, as long as you have features selected, only those features will be exported.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use the [Feature Class To Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000) python snippet.  Here is the general syntax.

> FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion (in_features, out_path,
>   out_name, {where_clause}, {field_mapping}, {config_keyword})

To output to a shapefile, make sure that your `out_path` is a folder (and not pointing within a file geodatabase), and that `out_name` has a `*.shp` extension.

Comment: Will this output to a shapefile?

Comment: If `out_path` is a folder, it will be a shapefile.

Comment: Yes, just make sure your out_path is not pointing within a geodatabase and out_name has a .shp extension.